# HttpInterceptor not working with angularfire2/Firestore API calls. Any workaround?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**Version info**

*Angular: 7 /
Firebase: 5.7.3 /
AngularFire: 5.1.1*

I tried to implement HttpInterceptor on angularfire2/Firestore API calls (Request URL: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects....) without success.

The requests are not crossing the Interceptor as @angular/common/http/HttpClient is not used.

Is there any workaround to integrate the Angular Interceptor functionality on those API calls?

Thank you

Comment: Opened issue on angularfire2 github sourcecode https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1990

Comment: Why do you want to intercept Firestore calls?

Comment: I have added an example how i implement a loading spinner in my app.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know AngularFire is a Angular friendly wrapper for the Firebase SDK.

The Firebase SDK does not use Angular Http Client so API calls from the SDK can not be intercepted.

For what use case do you want to intercept Firebase API calls?

**Edit:**

Here is a pseudo code example how i implement a simple loading spinner.

On the event which starts the Firestore operation you could set `isLoading` to true and as soon as you get the response from Firestore you could set `isLoading` to fasle.

In your template you could display a loading spinner with `*ngIf`.

component.ts

```
this.isLoading = false;

onEvent() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.angularFirestore.collection('test').doc('testId').set(data)
        .subscribe(
            success => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
    <loading-spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: Use case: Adding a spinner loader.