# Angular: intercept Firebase's API calls

Tags: angular, firebase, httprequest, angular-http-interceptors

My question is very much alike to [HttpInterceptor not working with angularfire2/Firestore API calls. Any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753889/httpinterceptor-not-working-with-angularfire2-firestore-api-calls-any-workaroun) but my use case is different.

I simply want to see when a request has been made to Firebase and if a request has been made, I could then up a counter. The counter will be used to see how expensive some users are, how expensive playing games on my web app are etc. Basically some kind of insights.

[According to the firebase team](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1990) they are not planning on making Firebase and HttpInterceptor work together any time soon.

I already figured out some kind of solution for my use case, although it isn't really. My somewhat of a solution is to create a service and call that service everytime I make a request in other services. Right now this would work perfectly within my application, but my application is growing and keeps on getting bigger and soon enough I will forget to call the service from time to time which will be an issue because then I won't have (accurate enough) insights into how many requests have been made, so I basically want to centralize the logic in one single place without having to remember that I always have to call that one service.

Anyone has a solution for this? Can I intercept other requests that have not been made with HttpClient?

Comment: Not with Angular's interceptors, they plug into HttpClient not the underlying XHR.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there, to your knowledge, a way to intercept the underlying XHR requests though that is fairly supported in Angular?

Comment: You could do it with a service worker, or maybe by stubbing out XHR yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43813770/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796951/3001761